# Why this is valid code and what do we call it

Tags: javascript

Recently i stumbled on below code and i thought it is an invalid block of code but i am wrong.

```js
[
 (function (a) {
   console.log(a);
 })(5)
]
```

and this

```js
{
  (function (a) {
   console.log(a);
  })(5)
}
```

I wonder why above code is valid in javascript and how it is different from

```js
(function (a) {
  console.log(a);
})(5)
```

and what do we call it

Comment: `why above code is valid` What do you mean? Because that's how JavaScript works. The first one is an array with one element: whetever the function returns (in this case undefined). The second one is just a block of code with a function call. Note that both are pretty much just a waste of characters and readability. Stick to the last one.

Comment: The first one is just an array with one element, which is a result of immediate function invocation (undefined, in this case). The second one is fine too, curly braces are valid [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) construction in javascript, so nothing special about it.

Comment: thanks @freakish for response,i am not an advanced js programmer, can you can tell me is there any difference between above code and array assigned to a variable?

Comment: @nivas You don't have any array assignment here. So I'm not sure what exactly you are refering to. If assignment comes into play then that's a different story.

Comment: like this one `var a = ['above function here'];`

Comment: @nivas Ok, so that code now makes sense. Because you create an array, and initialize it with whatever the function returns **and** assign it to a variable. Therefore you can reuse that array (and its members) later for whatever reason you have. The original code you've posted is not reusable (or rather: the data it produces is not reusable), the array will be destroyed after its creation, because it is not assigned to a variable.

Comment: As someone not very familiar with JavaScript, this question and its comments/answers were interesting to read and informative. I guess I'm not the only one, currently votes are +3|-3.

Answer (score 0):

```js
[
 (function (a) {
   console.log(a);
 })(5),
(function (a) {
   console.log(a);
 })(6),
]
```

This is a valid code. It is a array of self executing functions. (AKA immediate functions)
In this code, both functions will run.

The other one with curly brackets is just a function call decorated by code block. Nothing special or invalid about it, exactly the same as the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so let me try to answer the question based on comments.

> why above code is valid

This kind of question always has only one answer: because that's how JavaScript works. But let me dive into details.

This code:

```
[
 (function (a) {
   console.log(a);
 })(5)
];
```

and this

```
{
 (function (a) {
   console.log(a);
 })(5)
}
```

is functionally equivalent to this

```
 (function (a) {
   console.log(a);
 })(5);
```

The first one creates a temporary array with exactly one element: whatever the function returns (in this case it returns nothing, i.e. undefined).  Then the array is destroyed (because there is nothing referencing it) which begs to ask the question: why did we create it in the first place?

The second one is just a block of code. That's what `{}` do when they are not used as object, e.g.

```
{
    var x = 1;
    console.log(x);
}
```

All in all: using additional brackets `[]` or `{}` is just a waste of characters and what is worse, it confuses the reader. Because the intention is not clear.

However this code:

```
var a = [
 (function (a) {
   console.log(a);
 })(5)
];
```

is a different story. Now you have an array initialized with exactly one element, which is whatever the inner function returns (undefined in this case). You can use later for whatever you want, like `console.log(a.length);`. More useful would be to return something from the function:

```
var a = [
 (function (a) {
   return a > 0;
 })(5)
];
```

Now `a` is the same as `[true]` and perhaps having an array with this value is useful later.

Personally I wouldn't go with this kind of array initialization. That's because it still is hard to read it and the intention is not clear.